# Azure Devops Trigger - Saving to dev triggers other pipelines as well

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-triggers

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - dev
    exclude:
      - '*'
  paths:
    exclude:
    - azure-pipelines.yml
    - pom.xml
```

The above yml file mentions trigger only on the dev branch, but when I pushed any changes to the master branch the pipelines automatically fire even though I have excluded it using `'*'`. I have mentioned it as `'*'` because I am not sure about the branch names I will create. I want the pipeline to be triggered only on dev. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, this is possibly caused by the same .yml file name on both dev and master branch.

[image]

[image]

Rename the files to make sure they are different.